# Gradient of the Contour Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

On the given contour map of a function f (just the map), at the given point, how do you determine (positive, negative, or zero) of $f_x, f_y, f_{xx}, and f_{yy}$? This is part of a study guide I have where on the test there will be some given contour map and I am suppose to figure out the signs of each partial derivative. My text does not mention it at all and I tried looking online with no luck. So if anyone can give me any explanation or any source, that would be WONDERFULL!

Comment: Is in your question "contour" of a function $f(x,y)$ the locus of points $(z,x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ s.t. $z=f(x,y)$ (also known as graph of $f$)?

Answer (score 3):

$f_x$ and $f_y$ are the slopes in the x and y directions respectively, so $f_x$ is positive when the graph is increasing as x increases.

$f_{xx}$ is positive when $f_x$ is increasing, so when the graph is increasing at an increasing rate, or decreasing at a decreasing rate as x increases. It is negative if the graph increases at a decreasing rate, or decreases at an increasing rate as x increases. The same is true for $f_y$ and $f_{yy}$ as y increases.